# Disable Java JIT for a specific method/class?

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

I'm having an issue in my Java application where the JIT breaks the code. If I disable the JIT, everything works fine, but runs 10-20x slower.

Is there any way to disable the JIT for a specific method or class?

Edit: 
I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, getting the same results both with:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9) (6b20-1.9-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

and:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Did you file a bug already? Or did you find an existing bug, which describes your problem?

Comment: Sounds very unlikely that it's due to the JIT, no? Couldn't it be due to a race-condition (since the timing changes when you disable jit)...

Comment: I'm only using a single thread. I'm busy looking into the bug, but don't really have the time right now. The bug occurs consistently after a specific method has been compiled by the JIT. For now I'm just setting the -XX:CompileThreshold option high enough.

Comment: Have you tried a later version of the JDK ?

Comment: Blaming the JVM should usually be pretty far down the list :)

Comment: I'll see who's to blame later when I have the time, but for now disabling the JIT for a specific method makes my problem go away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following option works on my JVMs, to exclude a specific method:

```
-X:CompileCommand=exclude,the/package/and/Class,methodName
```

Comment: Sun/Oracle Java 6 and above use `-XX:CompileCommand` option. See [`java` options for more information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), specifically for v8.

Comment: Sorry to dig up such an old post; if I were to use this with a named inner class would I delimit it as `com/domain/package/Outer/Inner` or `com/domain/package/Outer$Inner`?

Comment: I encountered the same problem today. After some experimenting, it seems that we should use `com/domain/package/Outer$Inner`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is one.
You can supply the affected classes you want to exclude JIT compilation at start-up:

```
-Xjit:exclude={package/class.method|package/class.method}
```

Comment: I get "Unrecognized option: -Xjit:exclude={...}
Could not create the Java virtual machine."

Comment: -X options are nonstandard.  They may change between versions, and are dependent on your JVM