# clearing Java\CPU cache programmatically

Tags: java, caching, testing, junit, jvm

I am trying to test some queue insertions and removal of objects timestamp. After a few test runs I have a significant speedup improvement of upto 80 times better results on the same code. This looks clearly a caching result either by JVM or the hardware\cpu cache, but I wish to get fresh results each run.

Is there a way to clear both\either of these caches programmatically from within the Java code?

Comment: This sounds more likely to be the JIT compiler kicking it. As how to solve it is beyond me...

Comment: why not simply run it for a while to let jit run and then start measuring?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: WHy is this a problem? The JIT is speeding things up, and that is the actual performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably due to the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) kicking in. The JIT will compile your bytecode to machine code after a certain number of runs to make it more efficient.

You can change the number of calls before a method gets optimised by setting the `-XX:CompileThreshold` option (default value is 10,000) or by [excluding your class from being optimised at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004340/disable-java-jit-for-a-specific-method-class).

However I'm not sure why you would want to disable the compiler and force your program to run more slowly.

Comment: Or he could turn the JIT compiler off completely ... though doing these means he will measure the code running in an unrealistic way.  The numbers may not be indicative of real performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design a microbenchmark, I would suggest using JMH.

It is 'the' microbenchmarking framework and it will take care of JIT warmup, dead code elimination etc. It also has out of the box support for various profilers including Linux Perf.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

https://github.com/openjdk/jmh